# ORDER BY clause is not sorting by alias in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a query like this:

```sql
DECLARE @Sortorder VARCHAR(5) = 'asc',
        @ColumnNumber INT = 9

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(csu.UserName, CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), csu.UserName) + 1, LEN(csu.UserName)) AS UserName, w.WorkItemId
FROM [tasks].[WorkItems] w
LEFT JOIN operations.CustomerServiceUser csu ON csu.UserId = w.AssignedToUserId
WHERE
    w.[ShowInTaskList] = 1 AND UserName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @ColumnNumber = 9 AND @SortOrder = 'asc' THEN UserName END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @ColumnNumber = 9 AND @SortOrder = 'desc' THEN UserName END DESC
```

When I do that the data is not sorted by UserName in any order asc or desc, but when I do this:

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(csu.UserName, CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), csu.UserName) + 1, LEN(csu.UserName)) AS UserName, w.WorkItemId
FROM [tasks].[WorkItems] w
LEFT JOIN operations.CustomerServiceUser csu ON csu.UserId = w.AssignedToUserId
WHERE
    w.[ShowInTaskList] = 1 AND UserName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    UserName
```

What am I doing wrong in the dynamic order by? The values are the same in the declared variables and in the case. To be frank I don't know what keywords I should pass to google ;) Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: How can you be ordering by both username asc and desc at the same time. Am I missing something? both your order statements will be true.

Comment: wow did not expect that one, thanks !! please put an answer under my question so that I could give a thumbs up ;)

Comment: How do you think both order by statements will be true? It depends what will be stored `@SortOrder` variable...

Comment: hmm there was an answer that in fact I'm getting the LEN not the UserName and that answered worked for me, to anwer your question is not at the same time, when you put in the sort order asc it will sort by asc and if desc then desc the problem was that it wasn't sorting when the case when... was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the column `UserName` and an alias `UserName`. It is the **column** value that is being used to sort the results, not the alias. While it is perfectly acceptable to use an alias name inside the `ORDER BY` clause, it cannot be used inside `CASE WHEN` statement.

The solution is to use a sub-query (or CTE):

```
DECLARE
    @Sortorder VARCHAR(5) = 'asc',
    @ColumnNumber INT = 9

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(csu.UserName, /* removed for readability */) AS UserNameCopy, w.WorkItemId
    FROM [tasks].[WorkItems] w
    LEFT JOIN operations.CustomerServiceUser csu ON csu.UserId = w.AssignedToUserId
    WHERE w.[ShowInTaskList] = 1 AND UserName IS NOT NULL
) AS SubQuery
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @ColumnNumber = 9 AND @SortOrder = 'asc'  THEN SubQuery.UserNameCopy END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @ColumnNumber = 9 AND @SortOrder = 'desc' THEN SubQuery.UserNameCopy END DESC
```

Comment: Why doesn't this crash when @ColumnNumber = 7? My first reaction was that it should crash since it's like writing `order by asc desc` (without writing any column names!) but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: @ZoharPeled because it will order by null and any hardcoded value is valid example: order by null, null, 2015, ''a' desc

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: Ok, I see my mistake, it's like writing `order by null asc, null desc`. thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The earlier solutions seems right but sorting is not good. For example I have three users r.koscinski_ some_super_user, some_agent_user. It sorts like that in ascending order like that: r.koscinski, some_super_user, some_agent_user, wher in fact should be r.koscinski, some_agent_user, some_super_user would this subquery be the "cure" for that?

Comment: The issue was that the data was sorted on one set of values (username) but displayed another set of values (a substring of username). I am not sure about the agent values, I suggest that you check for the same problem.

Comment: I do'n't know what you mean. The sorting is good for the short name but with te complex one like some_super_user and some_agent_user is not working it does not sort like it should

Answer (score 1):

You can use CROSS APPLY to make your code look more friendly. It does not affect performance:

```
DECLARE
    @Sortorder VARCHAR(5) = 'asc' ,
    @ColumnNumber INT = 9;

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(csu.UserName, CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), csu.UserName) + 1,
            u.UserName   ,
    w.WorkItemId
FROM
    [tasks].[WorkItems] w
    LEFT JOIN operations.CustomerServiceUser csu ON csu.UserId = w.AssignedToUserId
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEN(csu.UserName) AS UserName ) u
WHERE
    w.[ShowInTaskList] = 1
    AND UserName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @ColumnNumber = 9
              AND @Sortorder = 'asc' THEN u.UserName
    END ASC ,
    CASE WHEN @ColumnNumber = 9
              AND @Sortorder = 'desc' THEN u.UserName
    END DESC;
```

And example with the data:

```
CREATE TABLE #a ( aColumn INT, b INT );

INSERT  INTO #a
VALUES
        ( 1, 1 ),
        ( 1, 2 ),
        ( 2, 1 ),
        ( 3, 1 ),
        ( 1, 3 ),
        ( 4, 4 );

DECLARE
    @Sortorder VARCHAR(5) = 'asc' ,
    @ColumnNumber INT = 9;

SELECT
    aColumn ,
    b aColumn
FROM
    #a tbl
    CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT
                    CAST(( tbl.aColumn + 1 - 2 ) * 5 AS VARCHAR(100)) r /*or any other kind of operation, such as substring etc*/
                ) shortcut
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @ColumnNumber = 9
              AND @Sortorder = 'asc' THEN shortcut.r
    END ASC ,
    CASE WHEN @ColumnNumber = 9
              AND @Sortorder = 'desc' THEN shortcut.r
    END DESC;


DROP TABLE #a;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this easily with Dynamic SQL (it worked for me):

```
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @SortOrder VARCHAR(5) = 'desc' ,
        @columnNumber INT = 9


SET @statement = N'
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(csu.UserName, CHARINDEX('\ ',csu.UserName) + 1, LEN(csu.UserName)) as UserName, w.WorkItemId
FROM [tasks].[WorkItems] w
    LEFT JOIN operations.CustomerServiceUser csu 
        ON csu.UserId = w.AssignedToUserId
WHERE       
    w.[ShowInTaskList] = 1 
    AND UserName is not null
ORDER BY' +            
        CASE 
            WHEN (@ColumnNumber = 9 AND @SortOrder = 'asc') THEN 'UserName ASC'
            WHEN (@columnNumber = 9 AND @SortOrder = 'desc') THEN 'UserName DESC'
            ELSE 'CustomerId' END 


EXEC sys.sp_executesql @statement
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easy and safe way is to use a CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserName ASC) As AscOrder,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserName DESC) As DescOrder,
        -- editor note: CHARINDEX is for '\' and not '\ ', but it messes up the code coloring system of SO, so I've added a space.
        SUBSTRING(csu.UserName, CHARINDEX('\ ',csu.UserName) + 1,LEN(csu.UserName)) as UserName, w.WorkItemId
    FROM [tasks].[WorkItems] w
    LEFT JOIN operations.CustomerServiceUser csu ON csu.UserId = w.AssignedToUserId
    WHERE w.[ShowInTaskList] = 1 
    AND UserName is not null
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @ColumnNumber = 9 AND @SortOrder = 'asc' THEN AscOrder
              WHEN @ColumnNumber = 9 AND @SortOrder = 'desc' THEN DescOrder
         END
```